# How to pipe stdin to a file using pipe and fork system calls

Tags: c, fork, pipe, stdin

I'm trying to pipe the stdin to a file using pipes.
The way I'm seeing it, is I need to make stdin be the write end of the pipe.
For code this is what I have so far:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int fd[2];
    pipe(fd);
    fd_set in;
    FD_ZERO(&in);
    FD_SET(fd[0], &in);
    if(fork() == 0){
        close(fd[0]);
        dup2(fd[1], 0);
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        close(fd[1]);
        select(fd[1] + 1, &in, NULL, NULL, NULL);
        if(FD_ISSET(fd[0], &in)){
            char buff[1024];
            while(read(fd[0], &buff, sizeof(buff)) != 0){
                write(1, buff, strlen(buff));
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The select statement does fire, but when I read from fd[0], there is nothing there.
Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Aside: Better `dup2(fd[#], 0), close(fd[0]),close(fd[1])` unless you want 1 duplicate handle open.

Comment: surely, you want `select(*fd + 1, &in, NULL, NULL, NULL);` There's no guarantee for any relationship between ordinals in fd[0] and fd[1].

Comment: @Deduplicator, you make a good point with the select call and read. For dup2 I close fd[0] before the dup2 call and fd[1] won't have an effect afterwards. But I suppose it is good practice.

Comment: The read-write loop should be: `ssize_t n;while(0<(n=read(*fd, &buff, sizeof buff)) write(1, buff, n);`

Comment: Also, put something into the pipe in your child process, before you exit it.

Comment: My goal was to have STDIN be redirected to the write side of the pipe so that the read side could basically just read the STDIN. Do I have to explicitly write STDIN to the fd[1] or can I pipe it in some way?

Comment: Someone has to do the reading and writing, if you want it piped. If you don't need it piped, but are instead happy with just having it as fd0/stdin, use freopen as i wrote.

Answer (score 0):

Just use freopen() on stdin. That should do the trick.

Comment: I'm aiming to use a pipe to transfer the data, otherwise I would.

Answer (score 0):

`dup2(fd[1], 0);` doesn't do what you need it to do. After the call, when something writes into your process's STDIN, it's not going to go into the pipe `fd[1]`. It just makes file descriptor `0` refer to the pipe *within your process*. Nothing ever writes into the pipe, so there's nothing to read.

Comment: yea I just realized that. Is there a way around it besides something explicit like calling write(fd[1], contents of STDIN)?